# convert two links into one in html

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem regarding my HTML and CSS. My HTML mark up is something like this

```
<div class="link-wrap">
    <h4><a href=""><span class="link-text">Link 1</span><span class="link-image">Link 2</span></a></h4>
</div>
```

and my CSS is something like this

```
<style>
.link-wrap {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
h4 {
  display: block;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
span.link-text {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}
span.link-text:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
span.link-image {
  color: #F00;
}
span.link-image:hover {
  color: #666;
}
div.link-wrap span.link-text span.link-image:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
```

Now as per my markup you can see the both `<span>` have converted into two different links and they have different hover state. Now I need that the two link will be converted into one. Just like example when I will hover the first span it should also change the second span hover state.

**Update**
Sorry to say you I can't change my markup. My markup will be remain unchanged.

Comment: What you're asking is not clear.  If they're wrapped with a single anchor tag, `<a>`, then it's just one link.  And if you can't change the HTML, then what do you expect to do?

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on the issue. If you want two links then you need two anchor tags. If you won't change your markup then that can not be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By studying your html markup and css I want to tell you that the css for hover does not work on span element, it works on a.
If you want to use an hover state for both the span just use

```
 div.link-wrap a:hover span.class-name { }
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The hover applies to the a elements, not to the span. To make both spans change at the same timer when you hover over a, use

```
a:hover span.class {}
```

As opposed to the structure you have.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/cDtdU/ for a working example